Is it safe to use the same IV for AES encryption?
I am using AES encryption in my application to encrypt user PATs (Personal Access Tokens) before storing them in the database. The primary goal of this encryption is to prevent anyone with database access from seeing the actual PAT values.
I am considering using the same Initialization Vector (IV) for all PAT encryption operations. The encrypted values will not be exposed to the frontend; the encryption is solely to protect the data at rest in the database.

Is using the same IV for all PAT encryption operations a bad idea?
Would it be better to use a random IV for each encryption and
prepend it to the generated ciphertext?

Here is the code I am using to generate cypher text. _key is stored in keyvault.
string EncryptText(string plaintext)
{
    byte[] array;

    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key);
        aes.GenerateIV();
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memoryStream.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length); // Prepend IV
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)cryptoStream))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(plaintext);
                }

                array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
}

Any insights or best practices for this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

The code uses the CBC mode (the default), not the GCM mode. The reuse of key/IV pairs is generally a vulnerability that is more or less severe depending on the mode (more serious for CTR/GCM than for CBC, see e.g. here).

No, it is generally not safe to use a fixed IV for AES encryption.
In CBC mode for example, if 2 different messages start with the same plaintext blocks, then with a static IV, their ciphertexts will also start with the same blocks.
Similarly, GCM falls apart with IV reuse.
I wrote this showing how easy it is to decrypt AES-GCM encrypted data if the IV is reused under the same key.
So, to answer your specific questions:

Yes, using the same IV for all PAT encryption operations is a bad idea
Yes, a random IV for each encryption is a good option, as is prepending it to the ciphertext to be used for decryption. The IV doesn't need to be kept secret.

Generating unique IVs via some sort of nonce-generated IV is another option, but guaranteeing uniqueness can be hard, which is why random IVs are often recommended. To keep the risk of collisions suitably low, rotate your encryption key often enough to limit the risk to an acceptable level. For example, rotating a 128-bit AES-CBC key before 232 operations (around 4 billion) would limit the probability of an IV collision to about 2-65.
